# Share an enum between a website project and a web service project

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, enums

I have an enum which is likely to be used in Project A(Website) and B(Web Service), but for now it is only used in project A.

I do not want to add the same enum in both projects, so what is the best practice to do it?

I am thinking of adding another project which will be referenced by both A and B, but I am not sure that it is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common functionality deserves being placed in it's own project to be accessible from all projects instead of duplication. It does not have to be a class library, you could define the enum in one of the projects and reference that project from the other one, but I'm inclined to putting in it's own project just for the sake of clarity.

Also, if you in the future decide to add another shared logic, you will already have a place to put it.